# Understanding some more complex boolean logic

Tags: python, logic, logical-operators

Can someone explain, step by step why True or not False and False resolves to True?

I understand that True or not False resolves to True or True and false,
but why does True or True and False resolve to True or False?

Comment: Can you put some parentheses?

Comment: Are there any parentheses involved ? if NOT false AND false gets evaluated first, the result is true OR false, resulting in true

Comment: If no parentheses are involved, perhaps the language youre using has a higher precedence for AND, resulting in it being evaluated before the OR

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence, so it's `True or ((not False) and False)`, and `True or (anything)` will be `True`.

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

```
True or not False and False
```

Corresponds to the following fully-parenthesized expression:

```
(True or ((not False) and False))
```

This evaluates as follows:

```
(True or (True and False))
(True or False)
True
```

The reason whey the parentheses are like they are is that the precedence in Boolean logic goes like this:

```
not  (like negation)
and  (like multiplication)
or   (like addition)
```

I'd expect this to evaluate essentially the same way in any mainstream programming language.